# How to get the Description property of a query?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a function that should return a query's description property:

```
Public Function qryDescrip(qryName As String) As String
'get a query's description field
    Dim db As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(qryName)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    qryDescrip = qdf.Properties("Description")
    
    If Err.Number = 3270 Then
        qryDescrip = ""
        
        'added for testing - if not found, append description property to QueryDef
        Dim prp As DAO.Property
        Set prp = qdf.CreateProperty("Description", dbText, "new description!")
        qdf.Properties.Append prp
        Err.Clear
        qryDescrip = qdf.Properties("Description")
    End If
End Function
```

Some troubleshooting I've done with query *MyQuery* that has the description "my description.":

- Calling *qryDescrip("MyQuery")* the first time returns "new description!".
- Calling *qryDescrip("MyQuery")* subsequent times returns "new description!" without raising the error 3270.
- When I go to design view of *MyQuery*, the description field still reads "my description."

I have a nearly identical function for tables that works great, but for some reason it's different for queries. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code runs nicely here, so something else is going on.

Comment: More troubleshooting: I created a new database with some test data and copied this function to a new module. They work fine. Something in my db is causing the description property to act funny.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gustav said your code appears to run fine for me.

One issue I'd raise is `On Error Resume Next` hides all errors and you don't turn it off after trying to access the property, so any other error is completely ignored.  Also, error handling should be done outside of the main body of code - between `Exit Function` and `End Function`

```
Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox qryDescrip("MyQuery")
End Sub

Public Function qryDescrip(qryName As String) As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(qryName)
    
    Dim NewProp As Property
    
    On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        'If an error occurs jump to the error handlers outside of the main body of the routine.
        qryDescrip = qdf.Properties("Description")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3270
            Set NewProp = db.CreateProperty("Description", dbText, "New Description!")
            qdf.Properties.Append NewProp
            Resume 'Clear the error and resume on the line that caused the error.
        Case Else
            'Stuff for other errors
            MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: I tried running your code but, unfortunately, I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the description if it does not already exist. If it is there then you never get the error 3270 and the function goes to the end. You can fix it as follows:

```
    If Err.Number = 3270 Then
        qryDescrip = ""
        
        'added for testing - if not found, append description property to QueryDef
        Dim prp As DAO.Property
        Set prp = qdf.CreateProperty("Description", dbText, "new description!")
        qdf.Properties.Append prp
        Err.Clear
        qryDescrip = qdf.Properties("Description")

    ' Property exists so just retrieve the description
    Else
        qryDescrip = qdf.Properties("Description")
    End If
```

Comment: Nope, that's wrong. Read the troubleshooting part. I'm passing in a query that has a description and error 3270 still occurs.
Also, your Else section is redundant since qryDescrip gets set the line before it checks for error 3270.

Comment: Your troubleshooting section reads "without raising the error 3270". Sorry I overlooked that you were already attempting to get the description which would obviously generate the error if the property did not exist. I have run your code and it works fine for me. Have you tried a decompile and repair/compact?

Comment: Just tried a decompile, compile, repair/compact. Good idea, but nothing changed. Something else is making my db behave this way.

Comment: As I said, your code runs fine for me. The only thing that I spotted that 'might' make a difference on your system is that you are not actually defining which property item you want to retrieve. Instead of using `qdf.Properties("Description")` try `qdf.Properties("Description").Value`. Grasping at straws here.